# Typescript interface variable clone

Tags: typescript, interface

I know the `interface` of the typescript is a Type, so if I define an interface, I can use it to define a variable. My question is that, is there any (pre-defined) method to copy a variable of an interface? for example:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  birthday: string;
}
let person: Person = <Person>{};
person.name = "bob";
person.birthday = "19000909";
console.dir(person);
let copyPerson: Person = <Person>{};
copyPerson = person;
copyPerson.name = "Alice";
//then the person's name is also Alice. because the reference of person is passed to copyPerson.
```

after I change the `copyPerson`, the `person` will change too. I know I can just assign the every property of the `person` to the `copyPerson`, but is there any method to make a separate copy of person? (By the way, if it is class, I can `new` an object)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
let copyPerson = Object.assign({}, person);
copyPerson.name = "Alice";

console.log(person); // {name: "bob", birthday: "19000909"}
console.log(copyPerson); //  {name: "Alice", birthday: "19000909"}
```

Comment: is there a way to get this to work with getter and setter methods?

My interface defines properties that have getters and setters and I want to clone only the getters and setters from the interface

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet not with `Object.assign`, read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Description

Answer (score 1):

Just had kinda the same issue so I'll post what I've found to help the other in my case:

If your object contains sub-object. When you use `Object.asign()` the sub-objects references will be copied and you will end up with the same problem but only with the sub-objects.

So you have to use another `Object.assign()` for each sub-object, but after using `Object.assign()` on the parent object since it will copy reference.

And you can also use this method to clone objects and sub Object:

```
let originalObject = 
{
    a:'a', 
    b:'b', 
    subObj:
    {
        c:'c',
        d:'d',
    },
};
//clone object
let cloneObject = {...originalObject};
//clone sub object
cloneObject.subObj = {...originalObject.subObj};
//now modification on cloneObject and its sub-object won't occure in originalObject
```

The spread operator can also be used with array:

`let clonedArray = [...originalArray];`

Answer (score 0):

To clone an Array or Object :

**Clone an Array :**

```
const clonedArray  = Object.assign([], myArray);
```

**Clone an object :**

```
const clonedObject = Object.assign({}, myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

`const object: CustomType = {customkey: "customValue"}`

`const cloneObject = {...object} as CustomType;`

This should work for you.